# How do I extract urls from hyperlinks using hpricot?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, hpricot

I'd like to get the actual url strings from the hyperlinks. I'd like my result to be stripped of html.

So, if one of my input strings is

```
<a href="http://target.com/resource.tar.gz">resource</a>
```

I'd like to get:

```
http://target.com/resource.tar.gz
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hpricot you access attributes of an element using square brackets (like you would when accessing elements in a Hash). So, to use your example:

```
doc = Hpricot('<a href="http://target.com/resource.tar.gz">resource</a>')

puts doc.at('a')['href']  # => http://target.com/resource.tar.gz
```